# $n$ distinct complex roots

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification

> Given a non-zero complex number $z$, prove that there $n$ distinct $x_i \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $x_i^n = z$.

Having fixed $z$, I can write $z = re^{i\theta}$ where $r = |z|$ and $\theta$ is the polar angle. By the fundamental theorem of algebra, $f(x) = x^n - z$ has exactly $n$ roots $x_1, \ldots, x_n$. But given such a root $x_i$, we have $x_i^n - z = 0$, so $x_i^n = z$.

My question is: did I trivialize the problem? I can use the fundamental theorem of algebra, but nowhere did I use the polar form or any other property of $z$, but I know that I need to in some way use it.

Comment: Note: the fundamental theorem of algebra does not guarantee that the roots would be *distinct*, which is the main point of this exercise.

Comment: You need to show they are distinct roots. You can show that the roots have multiplicity one, by showing that $x^n-z$ is co-prime to its (formal) derivative polynomial $nx^{n-1}$, because any repeated root is also a root of the derivative. This is fairly straightforward, because the roots of the latter polynomial are?

Comment: What is the purpose of even writing the polar form of $z$ if you don't use it ? The existence of $n$ roots is immediate "by inspection".

Comment: If you're meant to find the n roots explicitly, consider what $x$ must look like in polar form in order to satisfy $x^n=re^{i\theta}$.

Answer (score 1):

You obtain the roots explicitly by means of the polar form, noting that the argument is undetermined to a multiple of $2\pi$:

$$x^n=|z|e^{\angle z+i2k\pi}$$ and

$$x=\sqrt[n]{|z|}e^{\angle z+i2k\pi/n}=\sqrt[n]{|z|}e^{\angle z/n}e^{i2k\pi/n}.$$

---

Now we can show that there are $n$ distinct values of

$$\cos\frac{2k\pi}n+i\sin\frac{2k\pi}n.$$ By periodicity all these values repeat for every other $n$ value of $k$ and there cannot be more than $n$ roots. Now

$$e^{i\theta}=e^{i\phi}\iff e^{i(\phi-\theta)}=1$$ and $\phi-\theta=2m\pi$, and this cannot happen with $k\in\{0,\cdots n-1\}$ unless $\phi=\theta$.